# Python Django: Use dumpdata for single model with m2m field and mySql

Tags: python, mysql, django, m2m, dumpdata

I have a model `Lecture` with some `m2m` fields in it, which I would like to dump using `dumpdata`.

But whenever I call `python manage.py dumpdata cms.lecture` I get the following error

> CommandError: Unable to serialize database: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'.

Is this because of the `m2m-field` or what could be the problem here?

My Database is MySql (version 5.6.12) and I'm using Django 1.5.1. I used Sqlite before and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source :](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/issues/155)

Putting

```
self.serialize = False
```

into `managers.py` (around line 75) seems to fix the issue for me.

**Edit**: of course, adding it to the `Field.init` call as `serialize=False` is a much better idea.
**Edit2**: additionally null used to be set to True but now defaults to `False` and perhaps should also be added to the constructor.